# Estimating Error due to replacing the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (\frac{1}{2})^n$ by the first $n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

**Question:** Estimating Error due to replacing the sum $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} (\frac{1}{2})^n$ by the first $n$ terms

All I can really say at this point is that the remainder $R_n$ when summing the first $n$ terms will be:

$$R_n = a_n [\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n+1} + (\frac{1}{2})^2\frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + (\frac{1}{2})^3\frac{1}{(n+1)^3} + ...]$$

Where $a_n = \frac{1}{n!} (\frac{1}{2})^n$. I can technically restrict $R_n$ by the following:

$$R_n < a_n[\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{n+1} + (\frac{1}{2})^2 \frac{1}{(n+1)^2} + ...] = a_n\sum(\frac{1}{2(n+1)})^p$$

I am suppose to conclude that the error bounds $R_n < \frac{a_n}{2n+1}$, can anyone help me make that conclusion?

Comment: Are you familiar with any of the remainder estimates from [Taylor's Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder)?

Comment: You’re mixing indices... anyway, $\sum_{p \geq 1}{\frac{1}{(2(n+1)^p)}}=\frac{1}{2n+1}$ so you’re good.

Comment: The second term in brackets (in both displays) should be $\left( \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 \frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$.  [Rising factorials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials) are not powers.

Comment: @MarkViola I am not familiar with this, but there should be a solution that does not require it.

Comment: @Mindlack could you explain your line of thought, your $\frac{1}{2n+1}$ conclusion is not obvious to me.

Comment: What do you know of geometric series: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that we have

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty \frac{1}{m!2^m}&=\frac{1}{n!2^n}\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!2^n}{m!2^m}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n!2^n}\sum_{m=n+1}^\infty \frac{n!}{m!2^{m-n}}\\\\
&=\frac{1}{n!2^n}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{n!}{(m+n)!2^{m}}\\\\
&\le \frac1{n!2^n}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac1{(n+1)^m2^m}\\\\
&=\frac1{n!2^n}\frac{\frac1{2(n+1)}}{1-\frac1{2(n+1)}}\\\\
&=\frac1{(2n+1)n!2^n}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Which inequality have you used line 4?

Comment: @EDX Note that $$\frac{n!}{(m+n)!}=\frac1{(n+1)(n+2)\cdots (n+m)}\le \frac{1}{\underbrace{(n+1)(n+1)\cdots (n+1)}_{m\,\,\text{times}}}$$

Comment: Its ok thanks  :)

Comment: @EDX You're welcome.